# ui-router is reloading controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router 1.0.6.

Every time I return to an url (using ui-sref) it reloads the controller. I would like to avoid that and to load the controller only the first time it is accessed.

In this example [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/UXrdXdpmYEsnACiZjYvT): every time I switch repeatedly between Hello and About it logs the console.

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be wrapped in a parent controller to track who's already loaded

Here is a working example: [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/eTGtxGajG6Wu3UT4ZSIv)

Basically you **create another controller** that holds an object with an empty list:

```
myApp.controller('ModuleNumCtrl', function() {
  loadedCtrl = {};
});
```

And **set** it to be [parent](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states) by setting the **abstract** attribute to **true**:

```
var parentState = {
  abstract: true,
  name: 'parent',
  controller: 'ModuleNumCtrl'
};
```

Then you set the the exiting controllers to be his children by **prefixing** their names with **'parent.'**

```
var helloState = {
  name: 'parent.hello',
  url: '/hello',
  template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>',
  controller: 'ModuleTwoCtrl'
};

var aboutState = {
  name: 'parent.about',
  url: '/about',
  template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>',
  controller: 'ModuleOneCtrl'
};

$stateProvider.state(parentState);
$stateProvider.state(helloState);
$stateProvider.state(aboutState);
```

Then on each controller you want to load only once, you can add it to the list the first time it's loaded and the code that you want to run only once put in an if statement:

```
myApp.controller('ModuleOneCtrl', function() {

  if (!loadedCtrl.one) {
    console.log("One");
  }

  loadedCtrl.one = true;

});
```

Last thing, don't forget to change the **HTML** with the new **controllers names**:

```
<a ui-sref="parent.hello" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a>
<a ui-sref="parent.about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>
```

Comment: With this solution is the scope of the controller reinitialized every time? I would like to avoid that.

Comment: The parent will not reinitialize each time so you can put the code and any data you wanna save, on the parent controller and trigger it from the child only once, It's the simplest solution I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

There's a plugin for ui-router which can do that, named sticky-states: https://github.com/ui-router/sticky-states

I would build on top of your plunker, but i can't find a CDN that's hosting sticky states. I found a CDN for ui-router-extras which is the equivalent for sticky states in ui-router 0.x, but for 1.x that won't work.

What you'll need to do is

1) Add the plugin. The github page for sticky-states gives instructions on how to do this, which i'll replicate here:

```
import {StickyStatesPlugin} from "ui-router-sticky-states";

angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']).config(function($uiRouterProvider) {
  $uiRouterProvider.plugin(StickyStatesPlugin);
});
```

2) For the state definitions that you want to remain active, add the property `sticky: true`, as in:

```
var aboutState = {
  name: 'about',
  url: '/about',
  template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>',
  controller : 'ModuleOneCtrl',
  sticky: true
}
```

With this flag, moving from a state to a sibling state will not exit the old state, but rather will "inactivate" it. The controller remains loaded. If you try to enter that old state, it will be "reactivated". The state is now active, but the existing controller is reused.

Note that sticky states will still be exited if you do one of the following:

1) exit the parent of the sticky state
2) directly activate the parent of the sticky state

So you'll need to arrange your tree of states so that that either can't happen , or only happens when you want it to.